# Dynamic links with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

There’s my problem i’m a beginner with php thing and I’m stuck to put in place a pages with links that goes from a grid image with categories to a grid of image with the content of that categories.
For example I have a home page with Italian, French and chineses recipies displayed with flags of that countries and if a visitor click on a particular flag the recipies from that category will in a page called category.php.
I’m using a Mysql DBMS 
Can someone please tell me how to handle this.

Here's  an example of link I came with:

```
<a href="<?php specialité?specialite=1 ?>"><img id="im" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="images/france.png"></a>
```

Comment: <a href="<?php **echo** **"**specialité?specialite=1**"** ?>">;

Comment: You don't seem to be posting a problem, but requesting a design of a system, which isn't the purpose of this site. You should attempt to solve the problem, and then ask specific technical questions relating to parts which do not work as you expect, or if you find a specific function that you can't carry out.

Comment: I'm requesting a help to solve a technical problem here I don't know what part of my question let you think of a design or a system. which would take dozens or maybe hundreds of line to came across.

Comment: Naruto, I tried your suggestion but doesnt seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use as below,

```
<a href="category.php?<?php echo specialité?specialite=1 ?>"><img id="im" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="images/france.png"></a>
```

then

category.php

```
    <?php

$specialité = $_POST['specialité'];

if(isset($_POST['specialité'])){

# call mysql using $_POST['specialité']
# select table and get country related page and load page 
header("Location:your db_value");
}
```

or if you know POST ids use switch operator

```
switch($_POST['specialité']){
case 1:
//call mysql
break;
case 2:
//call mysql 
break;
case 3:
//call mysql 
break;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thank you THARANGA i forgot to put the <a> into a <form> but now it works fine.